# switching a project developed in vs12 to vs 13

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-assembly

I am trying to open window phone app project develop on vs12 After changing in csproject file tag `projectTypeguid` by `C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43` and target framework version with 8.0 and visual stdion version from 12 to 13 .

I can open this project, but still there is problem it gives about 23 errors and  3 warnings
These are the  Errors and warning:

- Error    1   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    2   The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    3   The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    4   The type or namespace name 'Notifications' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Warning  5   The path to the WindowsPhoneApp SDK [] was not found! C:\Program File(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\8.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets 526 7   Shared
- Error    6   The type or namespace name ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    7   The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    8   The type or namespace name 'Networking' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    9   The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    10  The type or namespace name 'Notifications' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    11  The type or namespace name 'IBackgroundTask' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error    12  The type or namespace name 'IBackgroundTaskInstance' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Warning  13  The path to the WindowsPhoneApp SDK [] was not found!   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\8.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets 526 7   BackgroundTask
- Warning  14  Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
- Error    15  The type or namespace name 'Background' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    16  The type or namespace name 'PushNotifications' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Networking' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    17  The type or namespace name 'Background' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error   18  The type or namespace name 'Background' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    19  The type or namespace name 'Background' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error   20  The type or namespace name 'PushNotifications' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Networking' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- Error    21  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskRegistration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error    22  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)      - Error 23  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskRegistration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error    24  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error    25  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskRegistration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error    26  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a lot of packages in your project, have you tried to restore NuGet packages? (http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2013/08/31/are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference-why-yes-i-am-so-kind-of-you-to-ask/9) NuGet Packages can be manages from Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> choose console or "manage packages for solutions"

The link also explains how you can "Empower NuGet to Self-Heal" (Right click on solution file). If this is not working, try go into "Manage NuGet Packages" and see if you have a "Install missing packages" label at the top.

It may also be that you have wrong target framework version in your project.
Try set Target Framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx to 4.5.1 (Should be the 4.5.1 for VS2013, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history)
 => You can double check in control panel -> add/remove programs that you actually have the targeted framework installed in you system.

If everything looks ok, go to your assemblies under "References", click on the reference that is unable to load, and make sure that "Specific Version" is set to false.